# Statistical dependence of mean annual soil evaporation and mean annual precipitation globally

Tags: models, precipitation, numerical-modelling, evaporation, soil-moisture

I am studying a simple dynamical system that represents a plant and water system, similar to [Klausmeier](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/284/5421/1826). In Klausmeier model the mean annual precipitation and the soil evaporation are introduced as separate parameters. However, there should be some statistical dependence of the soil evaporation be the mean annual precipitation. Anyone knows about a heuristic relation between the two?